# Tkinter e classe

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, tkinter

Sou iniciante em classes e tkinter e estou tendo um problema que acho ser por pouco conhecimento meu em POO.
No código abaixo, apenas uma label está executando, nem os botoes nem nada executam, oq pode ser? Dei uma diminuida na lista para caber aq na pergunta. Tive uns erros de identação ao postar o codigo aq, me desculpem.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

currencys_id = ['AED', 'AFN', 'ALL', 'AMD']

class CurrencyConverter(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master):
    super().__init__(master)
    self.master = master
    self.font = ('Courier',15,'bold')
    
    # Labels
    self.subtitle = tk.Label(self, text='Welcome to Real Time Currency Converter', font=self.font, fg='#ffffff', bg='#245985')
    self.toLabel = tk.Label(self, text='TO', font=self.font)
    
    # Combobox
    self.toCurrency = ttk.Combobox(self, values=currencys_id, font=self.font, width=10, justify='center', state="readonly")
    self.toCurrency.set('BRL')
    #self.toCurrency.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', currencyToConvert)
    
    self.fromCurrency = ttk.Combobox(self, values=currencys_id, font=self.font, width=10, justify='center', state="readonly")
    #self.fromCurrency.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', currencyConverted)
    
    # Entrys
    self.inputValue = tk.Entry(self, font=self.font, width=8, justify='center')
    self.inputValue.insert(0, '1')
    
    self.outputValue = tk.Entry(self, font=self.font, width=8, justify='center')
    
    # Buttom
    self.convertButtom = tk.Button(self, text='Convert', font=self.font, width=8, bg='#097FDF', fg='#ffffff')
    
    # Pack()
    self.pack()
    self.subtitle.pack()
    self.toLabel.pack()
    self.toCurrency.pack()
    self.fromCurrency.pack()
    self.inputValue.pack()
    self.outputValue.pack()
    self.convertButtom.pack()
    
    # position
    self.toLabel.place(x=230, y=100)
    self.toCurrency.place(x=50, y=100)
    self.fromCurrency.place(x=300, y=100)
    self.inputValue.place(x=70, y=140)
    self.outputValue.place(x=320, y=140)
    self.convertButtom.place(x=195, y=160)
    
    #def clickButtom(self):
        
def main(): 
root = tk.Tk()
app = CurrencyConverter(master=root)
root.title('Currency Converter')
root.maxsize(500, 200)
app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema esta no uso de dois gerenciadores de layout que esta sendo usado no script
pack é um, e place é outro, o mesmo objeto não deve usar os dois ao mesmo tempo, no momento não recordo a forma correta de usar place, se vc comentar esta parte o layout feito com pack ira funcionar

---

fiz um teste rapido com o place, e o tamanho do frame realmente influencia

```
from tkinter import *

r = Tk()
r.minsize(200,200)

f = Frame(r, width=100, height=100, bg='#aabbcc')
f.pack()

l1 = Label(f, text='teste1')
l2 = Label(f, text='teste2')

l1.place(x=0, y=0)
l2.place(x=90, y=90)

r.mainloop()
```

ao rodar o codigo vc podera ver que a label l2 fica cortada. Isso mostra que em seu codigo deve especificar um tamanho para o frame

Comment: Muito obrigado, realmente ja me ajudou a detectar o erro!

Comment: @lucas_boscatti tente começar com algo simples (faça apenas um frame com um botão) para intender como o place funciona, acho que o problema esta no tamanho do frame, tente colocar um tamanho fixo para o frame, e então posicionar alguma widget no x=0 y=0, e depois ir fazendo teste tipo: x=10 y=10.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme Elton Nunes comentou, ao "inutilizar" o **place** do seu código ele já apresenta mudanças. como nas imagens a seguir:
[image: mantendo o 'position']

[image: inutilizando o 'position']

Mas se a sua intenção for apenas essa, apesar de ser uma solução ruim, ela funciona. No entanto se vc estiver pensando na funcionalidade do seu conversor, se perguntando do porquê dele não estar funcionando, é por causa do seu código ainda estar muito superficial, não há atribuições de eventos para o click, por exemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox

[...]

# Buttom
        def nova_caixa():
            messagebox.showinfo('Olá', 'Eu sou o Goku!')

        self.convertButtom = tk.Button(self, text='Convert', font=self.font, width=8, bg='#097FDF', fg='#ffffff',
                                       command=nova_caixa)
```

[image: evento criado ao clicar no botão]

Espero que de alguma forma isso possa ter esclarecido alguma coisa.

Comment: Então, eu entendi esta parte, porém agora não estou conseguindo mais ajeita as posições dos meus widgets.  Estou ainda fazendo apenas a parte visual do projeto, sem as funções de conversões e clicks. De qual maneira agora posso reposicionar meus widgets? obrigado pela contribuição